# Detect which SQL columns changed on UPDATE statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the following Java code:

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(updateString);
statement.execute();
```

I know that after that is executed, doing `statement.getUpdateCount();` returns the number of updated rows. But, is there a way to know WHICH columns where updated?

The problem is that the code as it is, always passes the whole set of column values, even if some of those values did not change.

**I want to be able to tell whether a particular column, for example "NAME", changed or not, as a result of the underlying prepared UPDATE statement.**

**EDIT**: I understand that it is possible to do a SELECT for that column, get current value, and compare with incoming new value to detect if it will change. However, it implies another trip to the database. This question is to determine whether it is possible or not through some JDBC/SQL communication mechanism just after invoking that statement.

Comment: try to sxcute a query ex: select nameColimn from table after the updatequery

Comment: I don't have the previous value to compare. I am trying to see whether there's a quick-shot solution using SQL only, before creating ripple effects across existing Java interfaces and so forth.

Comment: if you don't have it's the same?after the update verify the result wit select query

Comment: My intention is to figure out whether is **possible** to figure out what columns changed through some SQL mechanism. I know that I can do a query before, get current value, compare with new value, etc.. The problem is that implies another access to the database, and I'm trying to see whether there's an existing programmatic interface through JDBC to check whether a given column really changed or not.

Comment: There is no such thing in JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

if you're just wholesale updating every column, regardless of whether the new value is different than the old value, then you'll probably have to programmatically select and check each column value prior to update.

so the pseudo code would be something like:

```
select * from table where condition
execute
foreach row in result
  foreach column in row
    if (column != newColumn) document.write(column != newColumn);

PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(updateString);
statement.execute();
```

Comment: My intention is to figure out whether is possible to figure out what columns changed through some SQL mechanism. I know that I can do a query before, get current value, compare with new value, etc.. The problem is that implies another access to the database, and I'm trying to see whether there's an existing programmatic interface through JDBC to check whether a given column really changed or not.